# Can I configure Tesseract to detect only single letters and digits?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying Tesseract ocr to process specific cards with a matrix like this: 
[image: matrix of numbers]

Is there any way to configure Tesseract to extract only single letters?

The problem is the columns of the matrix have letters as titles: "A B C D E F G H I" when I train using the BOX file each letter is detected, but when I execute the ocr process the letters are merged into a word: "ABCDEFGHI". I need the words separated because I need the bounds of each column (x, y, height, width) and it will make the processing of the entire column more accurate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could increase the interspacing large enough, Tesseract could pick up the spacing after setting variable `preserve_interword_spaces=1` (see [doc](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=1409)).